# How do I escape double quotes in sed?

Tags: linux, sed, double-quotes

Trying to figure out how to use a sed command to replace a value when the string i am searching for has double-quotes as part of the string.

I have a config file called ABC.conf that list out the release version like so; "ReleaseSequence": 1555

I want to use sed to change the release number to 2053

I have tried the following sed command;

```
sed -i 's:"ReleaseSequence":.*:"ReleaseSequence": 2053:' ABC.conf
```

I get the error message;

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'
```

I have tried to escape the doubel-quotes with [\"], '"""', and "" but sed doesn't like any of those.

Comment: You should not use `:` as the delimiter for `s` when you are trying to match a `:`.  Just do `s/\("ReaeaseSequence":\).*/\1 2053/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes are not the problem here. You have used `:` as the separator although your data also contains literal colons. Use a different separator

```
sed -i 's#"ReleaseSequence":.*#"ReleaseSequence": 2053#' ABC.conf
```

or backslash-escape the literal colons.